# How to use $isNull in this query to return empty Users array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, aggregation

Given a basic Mongoose user schema that uses timestamps (hence createdAt & updatedAt are available by default), I am trying to build a query that includes pagination server-side using aggregation.

So far, I have achieved the following that works pretty decently when there's data in the database and any filter matches any of the items in the collection.

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "_id": "61c331f4bd87407c01b81324",
            "bio": "",
            "surname": "Doe",
            "name": "John",
            "verified": true,
            "disabled": false,
            "username": "user1235",
            "score": 1
        }
    ],
    "pagination": {
        "total": 1,
        "limit": 10,
        "page": 1,
        "pages": 1
    }
}
```

However, this just returns an empty array if no item matches the criteria, losing the pagination part. My guess is facet part is the one not working here as I expect.

```
const findUsersQuery = await this.userModel.aggregate()
            .match(query)
            .sort({ cratedAt: -1 })
            .project({
                password: 0, email: 0, roles: 0, __v: 0,
                facebookId: 0, googleId: 0, createdAt: 0,
                updatedAt: 0, birthday: 0
            })
            .facet({
                total: [{
                    $count: 'createdAt'
                }],
                data: [{
                    $addFields: {
                        _id: '$_id'
                    }
                }]
            })
            .unwind('$total')
            .project({
                users: {
                    $slice: ['$data', ((page * limit) - limit), {
                        $ifNull: [limit, '$total.createdAt']
                    }]
                },
                pagination: {
                    total: '$total.createdAt',
                    limit: {
                        $literal: limit
                    },
                    page: {
                        $literal: page
                    },
                    pages: {
                        $ceil: {
                            $divide: ['$total.createdAt', limit]
                        }
                    },
                }
            })
        return findUsersQuery[0]
```

I have tried using $ifNull in some places, even in facet stage, in order to just return 0 or an empty array to return the same structure (keeping users array and pagination piece), with no avail:

```
.project({
                users: {
                    $ifNull: [
                        {
                            $slice: ['$data', ((page * limit) - limit), {
                                $ifNull: [limit, '$total.createdAt']
                            }]
                        },
                        []
                    ]
                },
                pagination: {
                    total: {
                        $ifNull: ['$total.createdAt', 0]
                    },
                    limit: {
                        $literal: limit
                    },
                    page: {
                        $literal: page
                    },
                    pages: {
                        $ifNull: [
                            {
                                $ceil: {
                                    $divide: ['$total.createdAt', limit]
                                }
                            },
                            0
                        ]
                    },
                }
            })
```

How can I use $ifNull (if that is the best approach) in order to keep the same response structure when no items match the criteria? Like this:

```
{
    "users": [],
    "pagination": {
        "total": 0,
        "limit": 10,
        "page": 1,
        "pages": 1
    }
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use the `$ifNull` here, your problem originates from the [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) behavior.

You want to be using the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` in the `$unwind`

> New in version 3.2: To output documents where the array field is missing, null or an empty array, use the preserveNullAndEmptyArrays option.

This will keep the document even if "empty", like so:

```
.unwind({
   path: "$total",
   preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
})
```

Comment: Holy sheep, did not think about the unwind step at all. Thank you so much! That did the trick. Merry Xmas!